# MQ Format MBAGGR01

Tags: ibm-mq, aggregation, ibm-integration-bus

I need to identify reason why message was send in DLQ queue.

I read message with RFHUtil and viewed that it have type MBAGGR01.

[image: RFHUtil Screen] 
[image: DLQ Tab]

I understand that this message contains multiple Aggregation folders. Is it way for resend or view data in Aggregation folders?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a Reason Code in the DLH of the message in the DLQ.  The Reason Code will tell you why MQ put it into the DLQ.

Comment: i didnt' find Reason Code 65536 in [Reason Code List](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqsao.doc/fm12040_1.htm)

Comment: That is not an MQ reason code.  If that is a correct RC then MQ did not put that message to the DLQ.

Comment: When you say your message "have type MBAGGR01", are you referring to the format field?

Comment: @MoragHughson yes.

Comment: @Roger I viewed this code in DLQ tab in RFHUtil.

Comment: 65536 is MQFB_APPL_FIRST. This suggests that the application that put it to the DLQ has invented some of it's own reasons. Can you please update your question with a view of the DLH (Dead Letter Header). This will show the reason but also the PutApplName. You should contact the owner of the application shown in PutApplName to discover what the reason 65536 means.

Comment: @MoragHughson I added img with DLH, but there is general name of WebSphereMQIntegrator9  without provide same details. I understand that is IBM Integration Bus.

Comment: I have added the 'messagebroker' tag to your question. Hopefully someone from IIB will see your question and be able to help - I can't find a list of IIB Feedback/DLH reason codes in the IIB section of Knowledge Center

Comment: @MoragHughson I replaced [messagebroker] with the product specific tag  [ibm-integration-bus].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did to resend this message with RFHUtil - on DLQ tab press the button "Prepare for resend". In syslog I found reason of DLQ.

But I don't know how to identify reason why message was send in DLQ queue without retry.